# How to cleanly handle nested try/excepts?

Tags: python

I have a method that pulls the information about a specific `gerrit` revision, and there are two possible endpoints that it could live under.  Given the following  sample values:

```
revision_id = rev1
change_id = chg1
proj_branch_id = pbi1
```

The revision can either live under

```
/changes/ch1/revisions/rev1/commit
```

or

```
/changes/pbi1/revisions/rev1/commit
```

I'm trying to handle this cleanly with minimal code re-use as follows:

```
@retry(
    wait_exponential_multiplier=1000,
    stop_max_delay=3000
)
def get_data(
        self,
        api_obj: GerritAPI,
        writer: cu.LockingWriter = None,
        test: bool = False
):
    """
    Make an HTTP Request using a pre-authed GerritAPI object to pull the
    JSON related to itself.  It checks the endpoint using just the change
    id first, and if that doesn't return anything, will try the endpoint
    using the full id.  It also cleans the data and adds ETL tracking
    fields.

:param api_obj: An authed GerritAPI object.
:param writer: A LockingWriter object.
:param test: If True then the data will be returned instead of written
 out.

:raises: If an HTTP Error occurs, an alternate endpoint will be
 attempted.  If this also raises an HTTP Error then the error is
 re-raised and propagated to the caller.
"""
logging.debug('Getting data for a commit for {f_id}'.format(
    f_id=self.proj_branch_id
))
endpoint = (r'/changes/{c_id}/revisions/{r_id}/commit'.format(
    c_id=self.change_id,
    r_id=self.revision_id
))
try:
    data = api_obj.get(endpoint)
except HTTPError:
    try:
        endpoint = (r'/changes/{f_id}/revisions/{r_id}/commit'.format(
            f_id=self.proj_branch_id,
            r_id=self.revision_id
        ))
        data = api_obj.get(endpoint)
    except HTTPError:
        logging.debug('Neither endpoint returned data: {ep}'.format(
            ep=endpoint
        ))
        raise
    else:
        data['name'] = data.get('committer')['name']
        data['email'] = data.get('committer')['email']
        data['date'] = data.get('committer')['date']
        mu.clean_data(data)
except ReadTimeout:
    logging.warning('Read Timeout occurred for a commit.  Endpoint: '
                    '{ep}'.format(ep=endpoint))
else:
    data['name'] = data.get('committer')['name']
    data['email'] = data.get('committer')['email']
    data['date'] = data.get('committer')['date']
    mu.clean_data(data)
finally:
    try:
        data.update(self.__dict__)
    except NameError:
        data = self.__dict__
    if test:
        return data
    mu.add_etl_fields(data)
    self._write_data(data, writer)
```

I don't much like that I'm repeating the portion under the `else`, so I'm wondering if there is a way to more cleanly handle this?  As a side note, as it stands currently my program will write out up to 3 times for every commit if it returns an `HTTPError`, is creating an instance variable `self.written` which tracks whether it has already been written out a best practice way to do this?